# javascript div length if value greater than

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-length

I want your help for how to get the length of div class if for example the value >= 20

```
<td class="total">23</td>
<td class="total">12</td>
<td class="total">3</td>
<td class="total">42</td>
```

in my example I have 4 records for class total. but the result should be 2 because only 2 records >= 20

this is my try:

```
   $(".total").each(function() {
      var val = $.trim( $(this).text() );
      if ( val >= 20) {
          val = parseFloat( val.replace( /^\$/, "" ) );
          length = $(".total").length // but this will show me all records which is not correct
          sum += !isNaN( val ) ? val : 0;
      }
    });
    console.log( sum );
    console.log( length );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should increment length value if your criteria matches

```
var length = 0;
 $(".total").each(function() {
      var val = $.trim( $(this).text() );
      if ( val >= 20) {
          val = parseFloat( val.replace( /^\$/, "" ) );
          length++;
          sum += !isNaN( val ) ? val : 0;
      }
    });
    console.log( sum );
    console.log( length );
```

Comment: Similar to @epascarello the parsing/validating of val is inside the `if` where it should be outside - but that's how it was on OPs code and the relevant part of the question is `length++`.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the cells on their innerText being greater than 20

```js
console.log(
  $('.total').filter((index,td)=>parseInt(td.innerText, 10)>=20).get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td class="total">23</td>
<td class="total">12</td>
<td class="total">3</td>
<td class="total">42</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A particularly useful side-effect of this in chromium-based browsers, is that you can highlight the element in the console and it will highlight the element on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce to to create an object containing `sum` and `length` of the values:

```js
let result = [...document.querySelectorAll('.total')].reduce((obj, itm) => {
  let val = parseFloat(itm.textContent)
  if(val >= 20) {
    obj.sum += val
    obj.length++
    obj.items.push(itm)
  }
  return obj
}, {sum: 0, length: 0, items: []})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="total">23</td>
    <td class="total">12</td>
    <td class="total">3</td>
    <td class="total">42</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```